# Sending Messages From NServiceBus Host

Tags: c#, nservicebus, nservicebus3

We have an Audit Message Handler and if any exceptions are thrown within this handler we would like it to send a log message to the LogMessageInputQueue which will be handled by another Message Handler.

Is it possible to send a new message from within an NServiceBus host process? The AuditMessageHandler accepts the handlers IBus in its constructor, but when calling

```
_bus.Send(new LogFatalMessage(ex));
```

No exception is thrown, but the message does not appear on the LogMessageInputQueue and seems to simply disappear...

All the handlers and Queues are on the same machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, figured this out all by myself :)

After the _bus.Send(new LogFatalMessage(ex)) we re-throw the original error, this causes NServiceBus to rollback its transaction and remove the message from the LogMessageInputQueue.

By wrapping the _bus.Send() in its own transaction, we stop the rolling back of the NServiceBus transaction from removing the LogMessage from the Queue.

```
using (var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
{
    _bus.Send(new LogFatalMessage(ex));
    ts.Complete();
}
```

Comment: If you are using v3, I would look at implementing the IManageMessageFailures interface to perform exception handling work.

Comment: @Adam we are using v3 and didn't know about that interface, will take a look at it